# How to update mysql after updating sphinx index attribute

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I've managed to use sphinx after some help from here :), now I have another issue with updateattributes, I can change the attribute in php and it works fine.

My question is how to update the value of the DB? is there a way for the index to be configured to update the DB? or the only way to do this is updateattributes from php and then update query just after it to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the database independantly. Ie your application should update both the database and the sphinx index.

Sphinx can't forward updates back to the database.